# Pandas outer merge two versions of the same DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge two dataframes that look like this:

```
In[14]: test1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,
                                    6,4,5],
                            'col2':['First','Second','Third',
                                    'Sixth','Fourth','Fifth']})
test1
Out[14]:

   col1    col2
0     1   First
1     2  Second
2     3   Third
3     6   Sixth
4     4  Fourth
5     5   Fifth
```

and

```
In[15]: test2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,7,2,
                                    3,4,5],
                            'col2':['First','Seventh','Second',
                                    'Third','Fourth','Fifth']})
test2
Out[15]: 

   col1     col2
0     1    First
1     7  Seventh
2     2   Second
3     3    Third
4     4   Fourth
5     5    Fifth
```

As you may notice, these DataFrames are almost the same, but each of them has one extra row that isn't in the other one (`3     6   Sixth` in `test1` and `1     7  Seventh` in `test2`).

I want to merge these DataFrames in such a way that any extra rows in one DataFrame are inserted into the other one as close as possible to their original location. Here's the result I'm hoping to get:

```
   col1     col2
0     1    First
1     7  Seventh
2     2   Second
3     3    Third
4     6    Sixth
5     4   Fourth
6     5    Fifth
```

I tried using

```
In[16]: pd.merge(test1, test2, how='outer', sort=False)
```

This outputs

```
Out[16]: 

   col1     col2
0     1    First
1     2   Second
2     3    Third
3     6    Sixth
4     4   Fourth
5     5    Fifth
6     7  Seventh
```

As you can see, the second row from `test2` is now at the bottom. Calling `pd.merge(test2, test1, how='outer', sort=False)` gives a similar result, but with the fourth row of `test1` at the bottom. Sticking to the order of entries in both DataFrames is crucial to me, so this is not what I want.

I've also tried `update()`, `combine_first()`, and `replace()`, but they give an inner or left join.

How can I get `pandas` to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) followed by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([test2, test1]).drop_duplicates().sort_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
   col1     col2
0     1    First
1     7  Seventh
2     2   Second
3     3    Third
3     6    Sixth
4     4   Fourth
5     5    Fifth
```

If you want the index of your new DataFrame to be unique, perform a [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) at the end:

```
df = pd.concat([test2, test1]).drop_duplicates().sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which gives a unique index:

```
   col1     col2
0     1    First
1     7  Seventh
2     2   Second
3     3    Third
3     6    Sixth
4     4   Fourth
5     5    Fifth
```

Comment: Somehow this didn't occur to me. I wonder how it's going to work in case of more than one "outlier" row in one of the DataFrames.

Comment: Update: this doesn't work if I add another extra row to one of the dataframes, e.g. `[1,7,8,2,...5]` instead of `[1,7,2,...5]`. However, this solution does work with the problem as I defined it in the question, so I'm keeping it as the answer. I'm going to keep looking for something more robust.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create a `fake` index in each dataset, and sort the resulting matched dataframe by this index

```
test1['index_fake'] = test1.index
test2['index_fake'] = test2.index

full_df = pd.merge(test1, test2, how='outer', sort=False)

full_df.sort_values(by = 'index_fake')
```

Comment: Well, `test1.col1.cumcount()` gives me `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'cumcount'`. It looks like `cumcount()` has to do with `groupby`, which I'm not as familiar with as I should be.

Comment: @Nikita OK buddy. try now

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work :( The output has 9 rows instead of 7, I guess it's because there are some additional unique pairs of values in `((col1, col2), index_fake)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you're talking about `on='index_fake'`, this just puts the two DataFrames next to each other with `index_fake` in between.

Answer (score 0):

### How about changing the column name for test2?

```
test2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,7,2,3,4,5],
                    'col2a':['First','Seventh','Second',
                    'Third','Fourth','Fifth']})
```

### Then do the merge that you showed in the question

```
test3 = pd.merge(test1, test2, how='outer', sort=False)
```

### But now, you can fill the missing data and remove the extra column

```
test3.col2.fillna(test3.col2a, inplace=True)
test3.drop('col2a', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

### Here are the results

```
   col1     col2
0   1.0    First
1   2.0   Second
2   3.0    Third
3   6.0    Sixth
4   4.0   Fourth
5   5.0    Fifth
6   7.0  Seventh
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn't accomplish anything - the row with `Seventh` is still the last one, when I want it to be the second one.

Comment: What it accomplished was merging your two dataframes and including the rows in one but not the other.  If you want to maintain the row order, you'd simply need to add an integer column with the row order to each dataframe prior to the merge and then pull these into a common column exactly how I showed for col2.  And then you can resort the dataframe to this column. I see that solution the next answer from Noobie.  The only thing I would add is that you should then reset_index() on the merged dataframe and then drop the sort column.